# How to user angular 2 directive inside polymer element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer-1.0

I am planning to use an existing angular 2 directive in polymer 1.0 componenet can anyone help in how this can be done

Answer (score 1):

A directive can't be used on its own. What you can do is to bootstrap an Angular2 root component with a selector that matches an element inside your Polymer element.

I wouldn't expect this to lead to something especially useful.

The other way around is probably the better approach, to use Polymer elements inside Angular applications.

Angular is primary a web application framework that can also be used inside parts of a web application.

Polymer is primarily a library to build reusable components that works also quite well as an application framework.